# How do I install Smartsheet Java SDK properly and use it in html?

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2

So I am trying to use SDK java for my web page development. I have html file that show my map. What I would like to do is to get my data from Smartsheet and convert these data to points on the map.

I figure maybe java SDK is the file that I would be downloading, so I took the following step to download the java SDK

1. Install brew
2. install maven using command

   brew install maven
3. follow steps in https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-java-sdk#install-by-compiling-directly-from-source to install sdk.

when I install the sdk, I got the following error in my terminal:

```
[ERROR] Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
```

I am not sure what this means, how am I able to fix the problem?

I tried downloading the python sdk, and it works. I would like to incorporate the code to my web page (.js file) and I am not sure how it works.

any helps / recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was clarified that you are looking to use the [Smartsheet Javascript SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-javascript-sdk) for your project. The JS SDK is built to be used with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and used on a back end server rather than directly in the browser. With this you will need to setup a Node.js project, perhaps using [Express](https://expressjs.com/), and build a server for your application. This way you will make requests from the Javascript in your HTML page back to your own server. The server will then use the Smartsheet Javascript SDK to make requests to Smartsheet and then send that data back to your HTML page, the front end of your application, to be displayed.

Comment: Hi, daveskull81. Thank you for always answering my questions. This sounds more complicated than I expected. I am working for this charity program and I am using my home computer. We do not have a server and I literally have to make everything from scratch.  Looking at your commend, it feels like that I have another challenge: to build a web server. As a novice developer, I am looking for a simpler way to convert my points to my google map. Do you have any suggestions (alternatives)?  or any advice on building a web server? Again, appreciate your comments.

Comment: I'm glad I can help! :) To accomplish this you could do a more Full Stack Javascript approach. Building out a backend with a server to do all of the work with the Smartsheet API that feeds the data to the front end in the browser. There are lots of tutorials out there on how to build out this kind of stuff. FreeCodeCamp.org is a good one to help learn Full Stack Javascript development.

Comment: great, I will look into that and do some tutorials :) thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want the Javascript library, [here](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-javascript-sdk).

Comment: Hi, thank you for you common. I am still getting the same error message saying option 6 is no longer supported, use 7 or later

Comment: hi I think my problem is that I don't know how to use commands to access my smarthseet. For example, the link you gave me contains some sample code :       
var client = require('smartsheet');
var smartsheet = client.createClient({
  accessToken: 'll352u9jujauoqz4gstvsae05',
  logLevel: 'info'
});
I am not sure where I should put these code, I tried to put the code in the html page with <script> tab and all the imports,  it says 
import com.smartsheet.api.*;
is an unexpected identifier.